# Calculating 19% taxes from total amount including taxes

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate the 19% of taxes from the total amount like this

```
<?php echo number_format($show['total']*0.19,0,',',''); ?>
```

The problem is, the product total price is 12990 so the real and correct taxes from this amount including the taxes is  2074 but with this code the result I get is 2468 and that is incorrect...

What is the correct formula to get the 19% taxes from the total amount including the taxes ( total to pay with taxes included )

Comment: what is tax amount?

Comment: 19% is the tax porcent and the correct amout of taxes must be 2074 but with my formula I get 2468

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have value which is effectively 119%, you need

```
$show['total'] / 1.19 * 0.19
```

Answer (score -1):

```
number_format($show['total']*1.19,0,',','');
```

Will give you the total.

```
number_format($show['total']*1.19 - $show['total'],0,',','');
```

Will give you the taxes only.

```
$taxesOnly = number_format($show['total'] / 1.19 * 0.19,0,',','');
```

Give you the amount of taxes already in total.

Comment: I got your question wrong  I think. You want the taxes which already are in the total?